# Linker error unresolved external symbol with only wWinMain MSVC 2019

Tags: c++, c, winapi, entry-point

This is the only code I have:

```
#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR pCmdLine,
    _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    OutputDebugStringA("Hello\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The wWinMain function with the exact same signature works in a separate project I created with the "Windows Desktop Application" (or something) template.

However I am getting a LNK2019 with the message:

`unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)`

coming from `MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)`

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition with MSVC 2019 on Windows 10. I created an "Empty Project" and only have a "main.cpp" file in the "Source Files" directory.

Can anyone help me try to diagnose what may be going wrong here? I am having no luck reading msdn/searching the web for the solution, it is very frustrating as I am just trying to get off the ground here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Subsystem to Windows in linker settings (for all configurations and targets).

[image: Subsystem Windows]

Visual Studio can compile for different Windows [subsystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture_of_Windows_NT), each requiring its own program entrypoint. An error saying "`_main not found`" suggests your subsystem is set to Console, since the linker is looking for a `main()` function.

If you have a `WinMain()` entrypoint (or `wWinMain()` for Unicode mode), it means you're targeting the Windows subsystem.